# When Biometric show at time application move on background - React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I created an application and for this application, I want to use password and biometrics when a user comes again in the application or reopens the application [Which means when the user goes to another application and then comes into my application after some time so I want to show Password and biometrics when user select password it's worked fine but when user go with biometrics and after successfully match it's come on same screen again [enter the password and biometrics screen]]

But I want when the user to select any option password or biometrics after the success it will go inside the application

I had check and I found when the user select biometrics my application gose in background mode again

```
useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", (nextAppState) => {
    if (
      appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
      nextAppState === "active"
    ) {
      console.log("App has come to the foreground!");
      // Foreground functionality that I want to do  // // Application come here again after the match biometrics
    } else {
      console.log("App has come to the background!");
      // Background functionality that I want to do  //
    }
    appState.current = nextAppState;
    // console.log('AppState', appState.current)
  });
  return () => {
    subscription.remove();
  };
}, []);
```

Here is the part of the implementation that I`ve created to handle the application state